# How to use Raven LoadDocument

Tags: ravendb

I'm having trouble querying RavenDB with even the simplest of queries, probably I'm doing something wrong, but after a few hours I just can't see it anymore. I've googled almost anything I can think of..

I have these entities:

```
    public class User
    {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string RealName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PictureUri { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; } 

    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
 }

public class NewsItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public List<WebImage> Images { get; set; } 
 }
```

I want to query these so I get a list of newsItems, but with the user information alongside it. So I read the docs and tried the LoadDocument feature, the index:

```
public class NewsItemIndexWithComments : AbstractIndexCreationTask<NewsItem, NewsItemIndexWithComments.Result>
{

    public class Result
    {
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    }

    public NewsItemIndexWithComments()
    {
        Map = newsItems => from newsItem in newsItems
                           select new
                           {
                               AuthorName = LoadDocument<User>(newsItem.UserId).DisplayName
                           };
    }
}
```

Which I try to use like:

```
var result = _documentSession.Query<NewsItemIndexWithComments.Result, NewsItemIndexWithComments>().AsProjection<NewsItemIndexWithComments.Result>().ToList();
```

Now I get the number of documents in my list, but the AuthorName is always null. If I don't use the AsProjection method, I won't get any results. Can anyone show me a proper example on which I can experiment further?

Thanks.

*_* edit:

That helped a lot, thanks :) Now for step two, I'm sorry if I'm being a bit newbish, but you'll have to start somewhere. In the newsitems there are comments, in these comments there is another reference to the userid. You can probably guess what I want to do: I want the user info for the comments with the comments as well.

new Index:

```
public class NewsItemIndexWithComments : AbstractIndexCreationTask<NewsItem, NewsItemIndexWithComments.Result>
{

    public class Result : NewsItem
    {
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    }

    public NewsItemIndexWithComments()
    {
        Map = newsItems => from newsItem in newsItems
                           let user = LoadDocument<User>(newsItem.UserId)
                           select new
                           {
                               AuthorName = user.DisplayName,
                               AuthorId = user.Id,
                           };
        Store(x => x.AuthorName, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.AuthorId, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

Comment class:

```
public class Comment
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

How can I query the comments and expand the results for that? Or is it better to create a new index just for the comments and get the user info analog to the solution above?

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there, you just need to store the field you are projecting.  Add this to the index constructor, after the map.

```
Store(x=> x.AuthorName, FieldStorage.Yes);
```

This is because you want it returned and available for `AsProjection` to find.  If you just wanted to use the author name in a where or orderby, you wouldn't need it.

Comment: That helped! Now at least I'm getting the results back. But this leaves me with another question (see the edit). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'm a little confused by your object model.  You have comment objects embedded in both your `User` and `NewsItem` classes, but there is also an `Id` in your `Comment` class.  Are comments in their own documents, or part of the other documents?  They way you have it now, it is denormalized in both places.  Are you sure you didn't mean to have a `List<string> CommentIds`?  Also - are there two different types of comments here?  Comments about a NewsItem and comments about a User?  Or are you just trying to show that the comments were made by a particular user?

Comment: Uhm, my bad, there shouldn't be any comments in the user class at all. Silly me, I was shuffling code around so much I omitted this error. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to include the comments in your AsProjection, you can simply index the entire object along.

Note that indexing a custom object will mean that you're not able to query on it using a `.Where()`. RavenDB can only query on flattened results (ints, decimals, strings, dates).

In order to, for instance, query on the title, you will need to create a seperate Property `public string Title { get; set; }` and map it with `Title = newsItem.Title`.

```
public class NewsItemIndexWithComments : AbstractIndexCreationTask<NewsItem, NewsItemIndexWithComments.Result>
{
public class Result : NewsItem
{
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

}

public NewsItemIndexWithComments()
{
    Map = newsItems => from newsItem in newsItems
                       let user = LoadDocument<User>(newsItem.UserId)
                       select new
                       {
                           AuthorName = user.DisplayName,
                           AuthorId = user.Id,
                           Comments = newsItem.Comments.
                       };
    Store(x => x.AuthorName, FieldStorage.Yes);
    Store(x => x.AuthorId, FieldStorage.Yes);
    Store(x => x.Comments, FieldStorage.Yes);
}
```

}